# jQuery news ticker, tucking behind other jQuery plugins and Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, news-ticker

I cannot successfully recreate this error in a fiddle. **[Here's a link to the site](http://webfro.gs/south/dev/cloud/)** (which will never come down).

When you arrive at the site, you'll see a news ticker at the bottom of the site. As you scroll down, you'll notice as you pass **1. Main Slider**, **2. Announcement Slider**, and **3. Images** for **Military, Nursing,** and **Georgia**... the ticker gets tucked behind all of these.

**How can I keep this on top?**

I've already placed this script to be called after the DOM is loaded, and before the slider script is called...

```
$(function() {
    $('div.latest-news').jNewsbar({
        position: 'bottom',
        effect: 'slideup',
        height: 25,
        animSpeed: 600,
        puaseTime: 4000,
        toggleItems: 5,
        theme: 's-orange'
    });
});
```

It's using jQuery 1.9.1 (CDN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can give the CSS Class `jnewsbar` the attribute `z-index: 99`

The reason that the other elements — which are OVER the newsbar — are over the newsbar is that they are all `position: relative` which makes them open for the `z-index`. And the newsbar is `position: absolute` — which is also subject to `z-index`

Due to the fact, that all of the other elements are coming in the DOM later, they are getting a higher "priority", than the newsbar.

So either you use `z-index: 99` or you move the `jnewsbar` DIV down in your HTML.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks! Keep on coding friend! Quick question if you wouldn't mind. How do you know which number to serve up as the z-index? Did you go through my entire stylesheet to get that?

Comment: @webfrogs The number `99` is just made up. I just chose a high number to make absolutely sure to be the top element, so you have enough numbers left for future elements. Of course you can take smaller numbers or higher ones.